# Mozila Firefox - setting the content of an iframe isn't working

Tags: javascript, asp.net, firefox, frame, mozilla

I am having a hard time trying to set the content of an iframe using Firefox browser.
In my code I have a label for which I set the content in code-behind on page load event

```
<asp:Label ID="lbnAdd" runat="server" />
lbnAdd.Text = "<iframe style=\"display:none;\" id=\"myIframe\" frameborder=\"0\" scrolling=\"no\" height=\"380px\" width=\"745px\"></iframe>";

ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Test", "<script type='text/javascript'>function MyTest() { document.getElementById('myIframe').style.display=\"block\"; frames['myIframe'].location.href = 'myURL'; } </script>");
```

I must say that this works perfectly in IE8, Chrome and Opera, but not in Mozilla. Javascript alerts me that frames['myIframe'] is undefined in Firefox, while it is object in the rest of the browsers. What could be the explanation for this, any suggestions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`frames["myIframe"].location` expects a `name="myIframe"`

You only have an ID.

If you also give it a name or use `document.getElementById("myIframe").src=...` it should work

Comment: Yes, that's the explanation! It solved my problem. Thank you a lot, it works perfectly!